# How to get functions’s start address using the unsafe package?

Tags: go, x86-64, memory-address, google-nativeclient

I need to get the first cpu instruction of a go function *(not assembly or cgo)*, but in golang, `&dummy` of `func dummy() {}` doesn’t lead to the function start address, but to the variable start address on the stack representing the function.

So in my example, `&dummy` doesn’t lead to a pointer, but to an obscure structure which I failed to find description in golang source code…

Comment: More precisely, I failed to further than [this](https://play.golang.org/p/sZX0cHNsAo).

Comment: I quess, you should look for type Signature in go source code(declared at /src/go/types/type.go) because functions are not passed by pointer but signature.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
functionLocation := **(**uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&orig))
```